# Debian: Need some explanation what apt is doing

Tags: debian, security, apt, backports

I have a jessie debian system (devuan to be more precise).
I now try to get packages from the jessie-backports and jessie-security releases.

But I do not understand what apt is doing.

That's what I really try to figure out: What is apt trying to tell me here ?

I know how to force an upgrade to ASCII. I now also managed to force my system to use jessie-backports; I still have no clue what apt tried to tell me in the description below.

I want to figure out what apt's problem was, because I am quite certain I will see the same kind of problem in the future (actually I just did on another system). So whoever has a better understanding of apt than me, if you know: please try to explain what happens...

I first of all start with gcc:

```
# apt-cache policy libgcc1 gcc-4.9-base
libgcc1:
  Installed: 1:4.9.2-10
  Candidate: 1:4.9.2-10+deb8u1
  Version table:
     1:6.3.0-18+deb9u1 0
        500 http://de.mirror.devuan.org/merged/ ascii/main amd64 Packages
     1:4.9.2-10+deb8u1 0
        991 http://de.mirror.devuan.org/merged/ jessie-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1:4.9.2-10 0
        600 http://de.mirror.devuan.org/merged/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
gcc-4.9-base:
  Installed: 4.9.2-10
  Candidate: 4.9.2-10+deb8u1
  Version table:
     4.9.2-10+deb8u1 0
        991 http://de.mirror.devuan.org/merged/ jessie-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 4.9.2-10 0
        600 http://de.mirror.devuan.org/merged/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

As you can see I have some pinning in place.
From what I understood I thought that "991" means use this package as long as it is newer. Here is my full pinning configuration:

```
/etc/apt/preferences.d# cat *

Package: *
Pin: release a=jessie-backports
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: *
Pin: release a=jessie-security
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 600

Package: *
Pin: release a=ascii
Pin-Priority: 550

Package: *
Pin: release a=jessie-updates
Pin-Priority: 560
```

It also seams the "Candidate:" lines indicate that apt will now switch to the slightly newer package from "jessie-security".

So first surprise:

```
# apt-get install -s gcc-4.9-base
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgcc1 : Depends: gcc-4.9-base (= 4.9.2-10) but 4.9.2-10+deb8u1 is to be installed
```

I thought with the above pinning apt would automatically pull in libgcc1 from jessie-security and so would resolve the above unmet dependency.

What's wrong here ?

Next problem:

```
# apt-get install -s libgcc1 gcc-4.9-base
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  antiword crda cups-pk-helper eclipse-cdt-jni eclipse-platform-data
  espeak-data fastjar firebird2.5-common firebird2.5-common-doc
  fonts-freefont-ttf fonts-opensymbol gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-atspi-2.0
  gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-glib-2.0
...
```

WTF ?

That's for sure not true. So obviously I completely do not understand something here. Even worse:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cpp-4.9 gettext-base lib32gcc1 lib32stdc++6 libatomic1 libegl1-mesa-drivers
  libgfortran3 libgomp1 libitm1 libobjc4 libosgi-compendium-java libquadmath0
  libsoxr0
Suggested packages:
  gcc-4.9-locales libosgi-compendium-java-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  adwaita-icon-theme ant ant-optional apt apt-file apt-listchanges
  apt-show-versions apt-transport-https apt-utils aptitude aspectj aspell
  aspell-de aspell-en astyle build-essential ca-certificates-java chromium
  claws-mail claws-mail-i18n claws-mail-pdf-viewer claws-mail-pgpinline
...
```

So this "apt-get install" command will remove half of my system.

I do not understand at all here what's going on...

Can someone please explain ?

EDIT: It was mentioned that I should not use mixed releases. I do not believe that this has anything to do with my question. But just to be sure: I removed all ASCII sources and removed all ASCII related pinning and downgraded the few packages I had from ASCII back to JESSIE. All of this does not change a thing: If I execute

```
apt-get install -s libgcc1 gcc-4.9-base
```

apt reports that it will remove half of my system.

Why ?

And there is also the first part of the question: Why does apt not auto resolve the dependency on libgcc1 if I just use

```
apt-get install -s gcc-4.9-base
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show your pinning configuration?

Comment: Of course: I just edited the post. I probably do not really understand what I am doing here...

Comment: ASCII is based on debian Stretch , you should not mix it with jessie.

Comment: Yes: That's why it has the lowest pinning and there are almost no packages from ASCII on my system. This also does not answer any of the questions I asked, like "Why does apt not auto update libgcc1, when I try to install gcc-4.9-base ?" Especially since both of these packages are from jessie (NOT ASCII, NOT STRETCH).

Answer (score 3):

You have a mixed sources.list : Jessie and ascii (stretch).

Remove ascii from your `sources.list`

Remove the following lines from your `preferences` file:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=ascii
Pin-Priority: 550
```

Run :

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

What is an *unmet dependencies*?

If some dependencies is not met during a package  installation , the installation will fail. The `libgcc1 (1:6.3.0-18+deb9u1)` depends on a exact version of `gcc-6-base`  v= 6.3.0-18+deb9u1. The current installed version is `6.3.0-18`

How to solve the unmet dependencies?

In your case append a pin priority `1001` to the old stable release, it will upgrade/downgrade your packages to jessie.

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=jessie-security
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release a=jessie-updates
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

Then upgrade your package.

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

In some cases you should use the exact version of the package to be installed to solve the unmet dependencies problem:

```
apt-get install gcc-4.9-base=4.9.2-10+deb8u1
apt-get install libgcc1
```

Why a lot of packages will be removed ?

apt install a package including its dependencies , if the package will be removed, those package will become unnecessary and automatically removed.

[APT tells you which packages are no longer needed](https://raphaelhertzog.com/2011/03/07/debian-cleanup-tip-6-remove-automatically-installed-packages/)

> Over time, some of those automatically installed packages become unnecessary because the packages that depended on them no longer do. It might be that they are using a newer version of the same library, or they switched to use something else, or they are able to do the task themselves.

---

To upgrade devuan to ascii , edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` by adding only the following lines:

```
deb http://pkgmaster.devuan.org/merged ascii main
deb http://pkgmaster.devuan.org/merged ascii-updates main
deb http://pkgmaster.devuan.org/merged ascii-security main
deb http://pkgmaster.devuan.org/merged ascii-backports main
```

Remove the `/etc/apt/preferences` file then run

```
apt-get upgrade devuan-keyring
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

[Upgrade from Devuan Jessie to Ascii](https://devuan.org/os/documentation/dev1fanboy/upgrade-to-ascii)

Comment: This does not work, because of failed dependencies and actually does not help at all. Because it does not answer any of the questions I asked.

Comment: I think it does answer this one: "What's wrong here ?".  I'd go for a full upgrade to ascii, as it's just been released as stable.

Comment: @IngoBlackman To solve the dependencies problem you should remove the ascii url , if you need to upgrade to ascii you can see the edit.

Comment: @GAD3R: Yes I did that. But in the end even after I removed all ASCII links (and downgraded the few packages I had), at the end the problem persisted as described in the question:  If I execute "apt-get install -s libgcc1 gcc-4.9-base". apt reports that it will remove half of my system. Why ? That was the question.

Comment: Thanks for the mentioning how to upgrade to ASCII. But that's really not the question. I try to understand how apt works and what the output means. I still cannot figure that out. Similar to the famous "The following packages have been kept back". I read tons of explanations about that and none of them make sense. Similar to why apt tries to remove half of my system if I try to upgrade "libgcc1 and gcc-4.9-base".